# コンストラクターの外でアトリビュートを宣言した場合のそれの扱いについて

Tags: python, class

Python3において、アトリビュートを宣言する場所が、コンストラクター(`__init__`メソッド)の外と中で、どのような違いが生まれるか。それに関するPythonのドキュメントの所在をご教示願います。

```
class Something:
    a = "<-このアトリビュートと、"

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = "<-このアトリビュートの扱いの違い。"
```

Comment: この辺の記事と類似(重複に近い？)の内容と思われます。[クラスの引数・変数・変数の参照についての質問です。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/45461/26370), [インスタンスの考え方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/71754/26370), [pythonのクラスにおける初期化メソッドの必要性](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/75817/26370) こちらPythonの仕様説明に該当するでしょう。[9. クラス](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/classes.html) 質問内容が少なくて範囲が広すぎる形なため、的確な回答は付きづらい(とても長い回答になるか、限られた側面だけを説明する形になる)と思われるので、もう少し範囲を絞った質問を考えてみてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

一例ですが、下記コードですと

```
class Something:
    a = "<-このアトリビュートと、"

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = "<-このアトリビュートの扱いの違い。"
        
print(Something.a)
print(Something.b)
        
sample = Something()
print(sample.a)
print(sample.b)
```

`print(Something.b)`のところでエラー(AttributeError: type object 'Something' has no attribute 'b')になります。その前の行の`print(Something.a)`では「<-このアトリビュートと、」が出力されます。
Somethingクラスの`b`にはインスタンスを作成しないとアクセスできませんでしたが、`a`にはインスタンスを作成しなくてもアクセスできました。

kunifさんがコメントに書かれたリンクを読まれたり、色々とご自身で試行されると理解が深まるのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

[kunif](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26370/kunif)さんのコメントにある、[Python公式ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/classes.html)の中で、[今回の質問の答えにあたる記述](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)を見つけられることができました。ご回答いただいた皆様、ありがとうございました。